# Change view native app Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, android, model-view-controller, sencha-touch

I created a very simple app to test a native Android app with Sencha Touch. I have two panels. When a button is tapped in the first panel, the second panel must open. In my browser it works great, but when I create a native Android application, only the initial view is displayed. When I tap the button the second view is not displayed.

This is my code:

```
Ext.application({
views: [
    'MyPanel',
    'MyPanel1'
],
controllers: [
    'MyController1'
],
name: 'MyApp',

launch: function() {

    Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {fullscreen: true});
} });

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.mypanel',

config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'mybutton',
            text: 'V1'
        }
    ],
    listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onMybuttonTap',
            event: 'tap',
            delegate: '#mybutton'
        }
    ]
},

onMybuttonTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    this.fireEvent('getPan1');
}
});


Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel1', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.mypanel1',

config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'mybutton1',
            text: 'V2'
        }
    ],
    listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onMybutton1Tap',
            event: 'tap',
            delegate: '#mybutton1'
        }
    ]
},

onMybutton1Tap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    this.fireEvent('getPan');
}

});

Ext.define('MyApp.controller.override.MyController1', {
override: 'MyApp.controller.MyController1',

config: {
    refs: {
        myView: 'mypanel',
        myView2: 'mypanel1'
    },
    control: {
        myView: {
            getPan1: 'getPan1'
        },
        myView2: {
            getPan: 'getPan'
        }
    }
},

getPan1: function(){
    var a = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyPanel1', {fullscreen: true});
    a.show();
},

getPan: function(){
    var a = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {fullscreen: true});
    a.show();
}
});
```

It seems to me that in the native app the event is not captured in the controller. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your button code :

```
{
    xtype : 'button'
    id : 'mybutton',
    text : 'V1',
    listeners : {
        tap : function(){
            alert("tapped button");
        }
    }
}
```

or if you want the function to be called from inside your controller (which is always preferable), then your button code becomes ::

```
{
    xtype : 'button'
    id : 'mybutton',
    text : 'V1'
}
```

and inside your controller you get the following

```
config : {
    refs : {
        mybutton1 : 'panelID button[text="V1"]'
    },
    control : {
        mybutton1 : {
            tap : 'tappedButtonFunction
        }
    }
},

tappedButtonFunction : function(){
    alert("tapped this button");
    // Do something
}
```

Also, try your code without using the overrides. It should work. I haven't seen it done before, where you override your own code instead of just simply coding.

Comment: In the browser its works perfect. But in the native app I got not the alert from the controller. The first situation with a listener in the view works in the native app.

Comment: So then can't you use the listener in the view like the first option I gave you ?

Comment: If I use the listener in the view, then I can't use the controller.

Comment: I think I know what I'm doing wrong. Is it true that I need to specify in a file which views / controllers / models / stores all should be in the package?

Comment: Not exactly. You know how you specify the names of the views, controllers, models, stores, etc in the app.js file under the Ext.Application code ? Well, you're supposed to put the code for those views/controllers/models/stores into their own folders with the folder structure as outlined by Sencha. If you don't they're not loaded in the correct order using application logic, and ur code cannot find them.

Comment: I could have told you that before, but I didn't realize you hadn't done it yet. I thought you had the different files in their correct folder organization, and you just pasted the code here from all those files

Comment: Then that's not the problem. May I ask why you're overriding the controllers and views ? I haven't seen that done before myself. Could that be what's causing the problem ?

Comment: I will even use it without overrides.

Comment: @ErwinVaes : I will add the overrides as part of the answer then, so that you can close the question since the comment did help :)

Answer (score 0):

The app.js

```
Ext.application({
views: [
    'MyPanel',
    'MyPanel1'
],
controllers: [
    'MyController1'
],
name: 'MyApp',

launch: function() {
    console.log("appstart");
    Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {fullscreen: true});
}

});
```

app/controller/MyController1.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.override.MyController1', {
override: 'MyApp.controller.MyController1',

config : {
    refs : {
        mybutton : 'mypanel button[text="V1"]'
    },
    control : {
        mybutton : {
            tap : 'tappedButtonFunction'
        }
    }
},

tappedButtonFunction : function(){
        console.log("Tapped");
        Ext.Msg.alert("Test");
        // Do something
    }
});
```

app/view/MyPanel.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.mypanel',

requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

config: {
    id: 'PanelID',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            id: 'mybutton',
            text: 'V1'
        }
    ]
}

});
```

But the controller catched not the event in the native app.